# Azure Service Bus Durability SLAs

Tags: azureservicebus

The [SLA](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/support/legal/sla/service-bus/v1_1/) for Azure Service Bus (ASB) provides a 99.9% uptime guarantee, however, it says nothing about recovery point objectives (RPO).

I'm trying to understand what (if any) SLAs are provided for message durability in the event of an outage.

I have a use case that needs to have an extremely low chance of message loss (near zero RPO), and I'm trying to work out if using [active replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters#active-replication) with two Standard tier SKUs in different regions will give me what I need.

I imagine that the underlying infrastructure for a Standard tier ASB is using something similar to [LRS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-redundancy#locally-redundant-storage) which in the linked article is stated to provide at least 11 nines durability - which would cover me. However, this is guesswork on my part.

Is there an official Microsoft source on ASB durability available anywhere?

Comment: [This question might be off-topic](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310983/are-questions-asking-for-documentation-off-topic). You might want to rephrase/edit your question to ask for information, not a link to documentation (this will prevent link-only answers too).

Comment: Do you think this might be an exception? I wonder if this is the rare sort of question that calls for a link - here, a link is inherently more valuable and creates lower risk of misleading readers because link rot would indicate the source is no longer valid - and it's important for the source of the SLA to be valid and current.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an official durability SLA, but as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-outages-disasters and in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-geo-dr#outages-and-disasters, the chances of data data loss are very unlikely.
If you use the active replication, then you will definitely get an extremely low chance of data loss.

Comment: Thanks (+1) - I had seen that source, and it's a bit vague. I was hoping for some hard numbers, so I'll leave this unticked for now.